# "Cannot GET" nested state with AngularJS ui-router, html5Mode, and Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

Currently I'm trying to get `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` working with AngularJS, ui-router, and ExpressJS. Given an abstract state `parent` with URL `/parent` and a nested state `parent.child` with URL `/child`, navigating to `localhost:3000/parent/child` within the webpage itself works just fine. However, when refreshing the page on the same URL (or typing the URL directly into the address bar), the browser returns a message "Cannot GET /parent/child".

We've been trying a few different configurations and such with ExpressJS and middleware. These setups do *not* solve our problem:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
```

returns the "Cannot GET" error.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("*", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
```

floods the (Chrome) Developer console with the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` for every js file, since Express is sending index.html for requests for js files within index.html using the `<script>` tag.

When navigating to a URL like `localhost:3000/parent`, the webpage displays just fine without any errors.

**Update:** I should mention that the request URLs for .js files are turning out to be `/parent/js/someJsFile.js`, for example, when refreshing `localhost:3000/parent/child`.

Answer (score 0):

It is common practice to keep your static resources in a location that can be isolated and served with the static middleware (for this very reason).

**Recommend**
Move your static assets (i.e. js files) into a location specified for static resources.

Then, the second configuration above is the fix:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/static")); //<-- JavaScript here

app.get("*", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
```

**Alternatively**
You could employ the urlrewrite middleware to accomplish your goal: https://github.com/kapouer/express-urlrewrite

Comment: Hmmm... still no luck yet with either solution. :( I updated my original question with some more info.

Comment: Ah...do you have the `<base>` tag set in your `index.html` file?

Comment: Yes: `<base href="/">`

Comment: Darn - you're killing all my best ideas! :-). Seriously, now lost without some more insight. This is a really basic setup and it sounds like everything is in really good shape. Next thing to try would be to use `path.resolve()` with `res.sendFile(...)`

Comment: Sorry, more specifically, `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname) + ...)`

Comment: Hm, that's not it either. Any idea why there are GET requests being sent for each of the js files mentioned in `index.html`? This only happens on a nested state. But for the URL `/parent` in this case, there is only one GET request for the `index.html`.

Comment: Because the index.html file is going back - then is interpreted - and all the sources are loaded. If you have any images in the index file with src attribute set, you undoubtedly see those too.